# Misleading legend description in the hats modal

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

The bottom of the modal showing a user's hats has the following text:

[image: modal legend]

Yet, [image: blue icon] doesn't show the hat *my* account is wearing, but the one the user whose profile I'm viewing is wearing. Similarly, [image: light blue] shows the hats which *that* user has earned on the site *I*'m  currently on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I adjusted the wording slightly:

[image: The legend now says "Currently selected hat", "Currently worn hat", and "Hat earned on this website"]

The translations on international SO sites haven't changed though, so they might still use the misleading wording. I'm happy to update them, but I don't trust Google Translate. So if anyone wants to let me know what the new Spanish, Portuguese, Russian, or Japanese versions would be, I'm happy to update them as well. Failing that, we'll revisit those next year.